# C programming: for loop - calculating money spend on employees

Tags: loops, for-loop

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    main()
    {
    int i;
    int Employees;
    int PricePerEmployee = 30;
    int total = 0;
    printf("How many employees?\n");
    scanf(" %d", &Employees);
    for (i=1; i<=Employees; i++)
    {
        total += Employees * PricePerEmployee;
    }
    printf("total: %d", total);
    return 0;    }
```

Let's say I have 2 employees.It prints 120, instead of 60.
Now, when I try to put i=Employees in the for loop, I get the result perfectly.
I'm confused.
i=1, doesn't stand for "I start from the first employee?".

Comment: This line total += Employees *  PricePerEmployee; Change to total += PricePerEmployee; since you are looping employee and using "<=". "i =1" is correct it start from first employee.. If you use "<" then your "i=0" is your first employee

Comment: for (i=0; i<Employees; i++)
    {
        total += PricePerEmployee;
    } Use this loop

Comment: Thanks it works, but I was expecting to get an explanation for why it doesn't work right.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get total many spend on employees then you don't need to use `for-loop` for this, you can achieve this by as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int i;
int Employees;
int PricePerEmployee = 30;
int total = 0;
printf("How many employees?\n");
scanf(" %d", &Employees);
total = Employees * PricePerEmployee;
printf("total: %d", total);
return 0;    
}
```

And if you want to use `for-loop` any how then do as @avinash suggested in the comment :

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int i;
int Employees;
int PricePerEmployee = 30;
int total = 0;
printf("How many employees?\n");
scanf(" %d", &Employees);
for (i=1; i<=Employees; i++)
{
     total += PricePerEmployee;
}
printf("total: %d", total);
return 0;    
}
```

Your code won't work as expected because :

```
total += Employees * PricePerEmployee;
```

means

```
total = total + (Employees * PricePerEmployee);
```

As `Employees * PricePerEmployee` is what expected as output and you putted this inside the loop. let `Employees = 2` and `PricePerEmployee = 30` then your loop work like this:

```
1st run :
total = total + (Employees * PricePerEmployee);
total = 0 + (2 * 30) = 60;
2nd run :
total = total + (Employees * PricePerEmployee);
total = 60 + (2 * 30) = 120;
```

Comment: I just edited to explain why your code is not giving expected output.

Comment: thanks, I was thinking the same way after scratching my head for about 20 minutes.